# AngularJS 1; splice from one array and push to another

Tags: angularjs, arrays

```
  service.checkOff = function(itemIndex) {
        var boughtItem = toBuyList.splice(itemIndex, 1)[0] ;
        boughtList.push(boughtItem);
            debugger;
    };
```

My question is what does the [0] signify in line 2 above?  I am trying to splice 1 item from an array and push it to another.  I need the [0] to transfer the item.  If I omit it, my code iterates but the value of the array item does not get pushed to the second array (boughtItem). Thanks.  Haven't found it in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly get the item without splice by passing index of it,

```
var boughtItem = myValues[itemIndex];
toBuyList.splice(itemIndex, 1);
boughtList.push(boughtItem);
```

Answer (score 0):

> what does the [0] signify in line 2 above

It signifies the first element of spliced array boughtItem;

> If I omit it, my code iterates but the value of the array item does
>   not get pushed to the second array (boughtItem).

If you omit it, then you will be pushing array inside an array.
Something like

```js
var temp = ["1","2","3"];
var tempSliced = temp.slice(0,1);
temp.push(tempSliced);
//temp.push(tempSliced[0]);
console.log(temp);
```